# Difference between ShortestJobFirst and OptimalScheduling

Tags: algorithm

I am reading Algorithm design manual 2nd edition.Can some one explain me the difference between ShortestJobFirst and OptimalScheduling algorithm.The algorithm given are as follows

ShortestJobFirst(I)
{

1. While (I = ∅) do
2. Accept the shortest possible job j from I.
3. Delete j, and any interval which intersects j from I.

}

OptimalScheduling(I)

1. While (I = ∅) do
2. Accept the job j from I with the earliest completion date.
3. Delete j, and any interval which intersects j from I.

I can not understand the meaning 
***"The diﬀerence between our scheduling and robotics problems are that there is an
algorithm which solves movie scheduling both correctly and eﬃciently. Think about
the ﬁrst job to terminate—i.e. the interval x which contains the rightmost point
which is leftmost among all intervals. This role is played by “Discrete” Mathematics
in Figure 1.5. Other jobs may well have started before x, but all of these must at
least partially overlap each other, so we can select at most one from the group. The
ﬁrst of these jobs to terminate is x, so any of the overlapping jobs potentially block
out other opportunities to the right of it. Clearly we can never lose by picking x.
This suggests the following correct, eﬃcient algorithm----"***

Example is in the The Algorithm Design Manual [(page 10/11 from this PDF)](http://www.cs.sysu.edu.cn/~lxm/DSA/textbook/Skiena.-.TheAlgorithmDesignManual.pdf).

Comment: See http://siber.cankaya.edu.tr/OperatingSystems/ceng328/node123.html

Answer (score 1):

They're both greedy algorithms with different cost functions. One chooses the job with the shortest runtime, one chooses the job that finishes first.

The job with the shortest runtime may not actually finish first if it starts later than another job, so for our greedy algorithm to work better we want a different cost function.

Consider:

```
----JJJ---
-JJJJ-JJJJ
```

The top represents `ShortestJobFirst`. As `JJJ` is shorter than `JJJJ` it gets picked to run however because you can only run one job at a time it blocks the other two jobs from running.
An alternative is `OptimalScheduling` which picks the first one to finish, represented as the second line.
Because it finishes equal to or before the shortest job, we will always be at least as well off as if we selected the shortest job.